# Finding files that changed within a certain time period

Tags: windows, cygwin, timestamp

I have a windows 7 box with a cygwin installed. For a given folder, how do I find what files' timestamp is in a certain range? I need the check to be recursive for all folders.

Comment: Note: best effort is: ls -Rlt and then manually looking at the timestamps.

Comment: If you use Windows Powershell, you probably can do that (the link contains irrelevant examples, but it demonstrate the potential): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx

Comment: Please check the manual of `find` command in cygwin. It may be possible that the implementation has support for time range search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find to search for a time range, but it is a bit of a workaround.

Create two temp files, for example temp1, temp2

```
touch --date 'yyyy-mm-dd' temp1
touch --date 'yyyy-mm-dd' temp2
```

This will change the timestamps for these files to whatever you set them.  Then use find with these files as the range:

```
find /some/dir/ -newer temp1 -not -newer temp2
```

Note, your search will return dates newer than, but not including temp1, and dates older than, including temp2.